# java - how to inject custom PreparedStatement's paramters

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to implement PreparedStatement, which won't work with sql DB.

Suppose I have the following sql query:

```
String selectSqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE f1 = ? AND f2 =? AND f3 > ?";
```

and the following code:

```
       //----

        prest = con.prepareStatement(selectSqlQuery );
        prest.setString(1, "val1");
        prest.setString(2, "val2");
        prest.setInt(3, 108);
        ResultSet rs = prest.executeQuery();
        //---
```

My question is how to implement setString and setInt methods for injecting params?

For now I save parameters' indexes and values into HashMap, but after it I can't make injection into sql query string.

Comment: what programming language? maybe Java. Which Database? how should this be related to regex?

Comment: @bw_üezi I use java programming language

Comment: What do you mean by "injection", you mean you want something like `"val1"` to be pulled from a variable?

Comment: yes Jon Lin
selectSqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE f1 = val1 AND f2 =val2 AND f3 > 108";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're writing your own driver, you can play with your class a little. Let's change the approach. If you have a query like this one:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND name = ?"
```

Replace the `?` to turn it into

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {0} AND name = {1}"
```

About your set methods, those will have to save your new parameters in an `Object` array, again matching against the index.

```
Object parameterArray = new Object[1];

public boolean setString(int paramIndex, String param) {
    if(paramIndex < 0 || paramIndex > parameterArray.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't set parameter " + paramIndex + ", The query only has " + parameterArray.length + " parameters."); 
    parameterArray[paramIndex - 1] = param;
}
```

Before executing the query, take advantage of your formatted string and set the parameters:

```
MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(query);
String newQuery = messageFormat.format(parameterArray);
```

The `format` method will replace the `{number}` substrings for the corresponding element in the index represented by the `number` between brackets.

Comment: thanks, but this method will work properly for only first call. For example if I call setTring(1,"val1") and after it If I call second time setString(2,"val2"), it will set val2 to age, because now in sql there are only two ?.

Comment: @user1686222 You're right, I've got another idea. Let me update my post.

Answer (score 1):

implementation of sql's java interfaces are part of vendor specific jdbc driver. You probably just need to get the proper jdbc jar file for you database. writing implementations of such stuff is usually just needed if you intend to write your own database driver...

Comment: yes, I am writing my own jdbc driver, but for now I am only interested in PrepareStatement implementation this part